# How to store session at remote server with ajax request javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, cookies

I start my server at http://localhost:8080, and try to query with ajax server at http://192.168.1.2/. I need to do samething to send set cookie command to store cookies at 192.168.1.2 server, and get information with ajax from it at localhost server.

So the code with javascript AJAX request:

```
let query = this.http.get('http://192.168.1.2/testdb.php');

query.toPromise().then((result) => {
   console.log(result);
   console.log(result.json());
});
```

I'm querying the server 192.168.1.2 to get from it information with storing information in session on it while script is working.

At server I try to do something and store information in session variable. But I can't because each time I send new query to 192.168.1.2 from my localhost, my server(192.168.1.2) set new session each time. If I not wrong I need to set cookie right, to store session at remote server.

My code at PHP server(192.168.1.2) is:

```
session_start();
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');            
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');     

  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump(headers_list());       
  echo "</pre>";         


  echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'session_id' => session_id()));
```

I got new session ID every time I query. To store session I need the id to be the some always. 
So How to do that to store session information at remote server?
P.S. Sorry for my bad English, it is hard to me to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to keep the session through ajax call because it creates a new http request every time.

SOLUTION is store seesion id at client side and send the id everytime with request to remote server. At remote server generate new session with the old id.
https://404it.no/en/blog/javascript_cross-domain_request_with_session

Answer (score 0):

a _SESSION variable is like a cookie. In your situation, you should store an Id in the session along with a user id send the userid to your server. The server would retrieve the userid and return the id.
Something like :

```
<?php
function getInfo(){
    $id = $_GET['userId'];
    //some id validations;
    $sessionData = $_SESSION[$id];
    echo json_encode($sessionData);
}

function setInfo(){
    $id = generateuserid();
    //some id validation 
    $sessionData = array('id' => session_id(), 'data' => 'data'); // the data you need to store;
    $_SESSION[$id] = $sessionData;
    echo json_encode(array('userId' => $id));
}

?>
```

And then for your Javascript you pass the variable in the url

```
let query = this.http.get(http://192.168.1.2/testdb.php?userId=someid);

query.toPromise().then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.json());
});
```

hope it helps !

- Nic

Comment: I know this solution, but want to store it in automatic by any query without id. May be I can somehow to use session_set_cookie_params?

Comment: @AlexanderZakusilo This methods is normally to set cookies' parameters like their time to live or their level of security, you can try. In your code, you are inserting a new session variable each time you make a call, that's why you have a different Id each time.